# DividerItemDecoration drawable draws fully opaque

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, divider

No matter which way I create, set its alpha, or assign a drawable to `DividerItemDecoration` in my `RecyclerView`, the drawable is always rendered fully opaque in my view. Why is this and how can I get my divider to be transparent?

I've looked in the source for `DividerItemDecoration` and there's nowhere that the private `mDivider` field is having its alpha modified. It calls `mDivider.draw(canvas)`, whose method comment says "Draw in its bounds (set via setBounds) ***respecting optional effects such as alpha*** (set via setAlpha) and color filter (set via setColorFilter)."

I've tried creating the `Drawable` as an XML shape with a transparent color. I've tried creating the `Drawable` as a single pixel PNG. I've tried setting the alpha on the `Drawable` programmatically with `setAlpha()`. I've tried assigning the `Drawable` to the `DividerItemDecoration` programmatically with `setDrawable()`. I've tried assigning the `Drawable` in the theme with `@android:attr/listDivider`. All of these methods yield the same result. The `Drawable` is rendered fully opaque.

Comment: `setAlpha` works just fine: `DividerItemDecoration decor = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chrome);
dr.setAlpha(32);
decor.setDrawable(dr);
rv.addItemDecoration(decor);`

Comment: That had the same effect as setting the alpha all of the other ways I tried. I did just figure this out though. I'll answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured this out. The problem was the background color of the `RecyclerView` wasn't set. I was looking for the divider to draw on top of the item views, at the bottom of them. But it's actually drawing the divider view *between* the item views, with the `RecyclerView` color behind it (if set) or else the color of the view containing the `RecyclerView`. I was looking for the transparent color to show through the light color of the item view, instead it was showing through the default dark color of the screen behind the `RecyclerView`. Problem solved!